# How can I read from a file where the name is given by an entry widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, tkinter, io

I'm new to python and even newer to Tkinter. I'm trying to have the user enter the filename in an entry widget and hit a button that outputs the contents of the entered file to the console. The problem occurs in the attributeFileName() method (line 7) after button_1 (line 46) is pressed. Here is my code below:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
root.configure(background="black")

def attributeFileName():  
   try:
     f = open(entry_1.get(), 'r')  # Tries to open the file entered by the 
       except IOError:
     print ("Cannot open", entry_1.get())  # If the file cannot be opened, 
report it back to the user
   for line in f:
     print line
   f.close()

def constraintFileName():
   print(entry_2.get())

def preferenceFileName():
   print(entry_3.get())

# *****Frames*****

fileFrame = Frame(root)
fileFrame.configure(background="black")
fileFrame.pack(pady=50)
attributeFrame = Frame(root)
attributeFrame.configure(background="red")
attributeFrame.pack(pady=5)
constraintFrame = Frame(root)
constraintFrame.configure(background="blue")
constraintFrame.pack(pady=5)
preferenceFrame = Frame(root)
preferenceFrame.configure(background="#51006F")
preferenceFrame.pack()

# *****File Frame*****

label_1 = Label(fileFrame, text="Enter Attributes file name:", anchor="e", 
bg="red", font="Times 25", width=25, height=1)
label_2 = Label(fileFrame, text="Enter hard constraints file name:", 
anchor="e", bg="blue", fg="yellow", font="Times 25", width=25, height=1)
label_3 = Label(fileFrame, text="Enter preferences file name:", 
anchor="e", bg="#51006F", fg="#45FFF4", font="times 25", width=25, 
height=1)
entry_1 = Entry(fileFrame, font="Times 25")
entry_2 = Entry(fileFrame, font="Times 25")
entry_3 = Entry(fileFrame, font="Times 25")

button_1 = Button(fileFrame, text="Submit", bg="red", font="Times 20", 
command=attributeFileName)
button_2 = Button(fileFrame, text="Submit", bg="blue", fg="yellow", 
font="Times 20", command=constraintFileName)
button_3 = Button(fileFrame, text="Submit", bg="#51006F", fg="#45FFF4", 
font="Times 20", command=preferenceFileName)
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

label_2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

label_3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
entry_3.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

# *****Attribute Frame*****
attributeHeaderFrame = Frame(attributeFrame)
attributeHeaderFrame.configure(background="red")
attributeHeaderFrame.grid(row=0)
attributeDataFrame = Frame(attributeFrame)
attributeDataFrame.configure(background="red")
attributeDataFrame.grid(row=1)
attributeListFrame = Frame(attributeFrame)
attributeListFrame.configure(background="red")
attributeListFrame.grid(row=2, pady=10)

label_Attribute_header = Label(attributeHeaderFrame, text="Attributes", 
bg="red", font="Times 25", width=25, height=1)
attribute_Name = Label(attributeDataFrame, text="Name:", bg="red", 
font="Times 20")
entry_Attribute_Name = Entry(attributeDataFrame, font="Times 20")
label_Colon = Label(attributeDataFrame, text=":", bg="red", font="Times 
20")
label_Comma = Label(attributeDataFrame, text=",", bg="red", font="Times 
25") 
entry_Attribute1 = Entry(attributeDataFrame, font="Times 20")
entry_Attribute2 = Entry(attributeDataFrame, font="Times 20")
attribute_add = Button(attributeDataFrame, text="+", bg="black", 
fg="white", font="Times 15")

list = Listbox(attributeListFrame, height=15, width=172)
scroll = Scrollbar(attributeListFrame, command=list.yview)

list.configure(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
list.pack(side=LEFT)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

label_Attribute_header.pack()
attribute_Name.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
entry_Attribute_Name.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="W")
label_Colon.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="W")
entry_Attribute1.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="W", padx=(50,0))
label_Comma.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="W")
entry_Attribute2.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="W")
attribute_add.grid(row=0, column=6, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")

# *****Constraint Frame*****
constraintHeaderFrame = Frame(constraintFrame)
constraintHeaderFrame.configure(background="blue")
constraintHeaderFrame.grid(row=0)
constraintDataFrame = Frame(constraintFrame)
constraintDataFrame.configure(background="blue")
constraintDataFrame.grid(row=1, pady=10)
constraintListFrame = Frame(constraintFrame)
constraintListFrame.configure(background="blue")
constraintListFrame.grid(row=2, pady=10)

label_Constraint_header = Label(constraintHeaderFrame, text="Hard 
Constraints", bg="blue", fg="yellow", font="Times 25")
label_Constraints = Label(constraintDataFrame, text="Constraint:", 
bg="blue", fg="yellow", font="Times 20",)
entry_Constraints = Entry(constraintDataFrame, font="Times 20")
constraint_add = Button(constraintDataFrame, text="+", bg="black", 
fg="white", font="Times 15")
label_Constraint_header.pack()
label_Constraints.grid(row=0)
entry_Constraints.grid(row=0, column=1)
constraint_add.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=15)

list = Listbox(constraintListFrame, height=15, width=172)
scroll = Scrollbar(constraintListFrame, command=list.yview)

list.configure(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
list.pack(side=LEFT)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# *****Preference Frame*****

preferenceHeaderFrame = Frame(preferenceFrame)
preferenceHeaderFrame.configure(background="#51006F")
preferenceHeaderFrame.grid(row=0)
preferenceDataFrame = Frame(preferenceFrame)
preferenceDataFrame.configure(background="#51006F")
preferenceDataFrame.grid(row=1, pady=10)
preferenceListFrame = Frame(preferenceFrame)
preferenceListFrame.configure(background="#51006F")
preferenceListFrame.grid(row=2, pady=10)

label_Preference_header = Label(preferenceHeaderFrame, text="Preferences", 
bg="#51006F", fg="#45FFF4", font="Times 25")
label_preference = Label(preferenceDataFrame, text="Preference:", 
bg="#51006F", fg="#45FFF4", font="Times 20",)
entry_preference = Entry(preferenceDataFrame, font="Times 20")
preference_add = Button(preferenceDataFrame, text="+", bg="black", 
fg="white", font="Times 15")

label_Preference_header.pack()
label_preference.grid(row=0)
entry_preference.grid(row=0, column=1)
preference_add.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=15)

list = Listbox(preferenceListFrame, height=15, width=172)
scroll = Scrollbar(preferenceListFrame, command=list.yview)

list.configure(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
list.pack(side=LEFT)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

root.mainloop()
```

My Output:

[image: Sample Output]

I expect the name of the file to be read from the entry widget and the file contents printed out to the console. However, instead an Exception is thrown. Here is the stack trace:

```
('Cannot open', 'test.txt')
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "gui.py", line 13, in attributeFileName
    for line in f:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment
```

Can somebody explain to me what this means, why I'm getting this error, and most importantly how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this function:

```
def attributeFileName():  
    try:
        f = open(entry_1.get(), 'r')  # Tries to open the file entered by the 
    except IOError:
        print ("Cannot open", entry_1.get())  # If the file cannot be opened, report it back to the user
    for line in f:
        print (line)
    f.close()
```

If an exception is caught, `f` is undefined and result in your unbound error. Simply move the `for` loop and `close` inside the try statement:

```
def attributeFileName():
    try:
        f = open(entry_1.get(), 'r')
        for line in f:
            print(line)
        f.close()
    except IOError:
        print ("Cannot open", entry_1.get())
```